# C++ Winsock App Access Violation

Tags: c++, winsock, access-violation

I am using the source code from the MSDN for the C++ Winsock Server & Client, on the server side I am putting most of the code in functions and am having a access violation error. My complete source is below.

Any help would be great, thanks in advance!
This is my j420s,cpp file.

```
#include "j420s.h"
//Source From : MSDN Winsock Server Code.
//Original Source : https ://msdn.microsoft.com/en-   us/library/windows/desktop/ms737593(v=vs.85).aspx
int __cdecl main(void) {

WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult = NULL;

SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

struct addrinfo *MySocketResult = NULL;
struct addrinfo MySocket;

int iSendResult;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

// Initialize Winsock
iResult = SocketInit(iResult, &wsaData);
if (iResult == 1){

    return 1;

}

ZeroMemory(&MySocket, sizeof(MySocket));
MySocket.ai_family = AF_INET;
MySocket.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
MySocket.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
MySocket.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

// Resolve the server address and port
iResult = SocketAddrInfo(iResult, &MySocket, MySocketResult);


// Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
ListenSocket = SocketCreate(ListenSocket, MySocketResult);
if (ListenSocket == 1){

    return 1;

}

// Setup the TCP listening socket
iResult = SocketBind(iResult, ListenSocket, MySocketResult);
if (iResult == 1) {

    return 1;

}

iResult = SocketListen(iResult, ListenSocket, MySocketResult);
if (iResult == 1) {

    return 1;

}

// Accept a client socket
ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// No longer need server socket
closesocket(ListenSocket);

// Receive FOREVER!
while (1 == 1){
  do {

    iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);

      if (iResult > 0) {

        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);

        // Echo the buffer back to the sender
        iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);

        if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {

            printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();

            return 1;

        }

        printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);

    }

  } while (iResult > 0);

}

// shutdown the connection since we're done
iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);

if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {

    printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 1;

}

// cleanup
closesocket(ClientSocket);
WSACleanup();
system("pause");
return 0;

}

int SocketAddrInfo(int iResult, addrinfo* MySocket, addrinfo*  MySocketResult){

iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, MySocket, &MySocketResult);

if (iResult != 0) {

    printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);

    WSACleanup();

    return 1;

}

return iResult;

}
// Socket initialization
int SocketInit(int iResult, WSADATA *wsaData){

iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), wsaData);

if (iResult != 0) {

    printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);

    std::cout << "Server closing in 5 ";

    for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--){

        Sleep(1 * 1000);

        cout << i << " ";

    }

    cout << "Server closing now!" << endl;

    return 1;

}

return iResult;

}
// Socket create function to create a socket for connecting to our server.
SOCKET SocketCreate(SOCKET ListenSocket, addrinfo* MySocketResult){

ListenSocket = socket( MySocketResult->ai_family, MySocketResult-  >ai_socktype, MySocketResult->ai_protocol );

if ( ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET ) {

    printf("Socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());

    freeaddrinfo(MySocketResult);
    WSACleanup();

    std::cout << "Server closing in 5 ";

    for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--){

        Sleep(1 * 1000);

        cout << i << " ";

    }

    cout << "Server closing now!" << endl;

    return 1;

}

return ListenSocket;

}

// Socket bind function for binding our socket to an address for incoming         connections.
int SocketBind(int iResult, SOCKET ListenSocket, addrinfo* MySocketResult) {

iResult = bind(ListenSocket, MySocketResult->ai_addr, (int)MySocketResult->ai_addrlen);

if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {

    printf("Bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    freeaddrinfo(MySocketResult);
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    std::cout << "Server closing in 5 ";

    for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--){

        Sleep(1 * 1000);

        cout << i << " ";

    }

    cout << "Server closing now!" << endl;

    return 1;

}

return iResult;

}

// Socket listen function to listen for incoming connections.
int SocketListen(int iResult, SOCKET ListenSocket, addrinfo* MySocketResult)  {

freeaddrinfo(MySocketResult);

iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);

if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {

    printf("Listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    std::cout << "Server closing in 5 ";

    for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--){

        Sleep(1 * 1000);

        cout << i << " ";

    }

    cout << "Server closing now!" << endl;

    return 1;

}

return iResult;

}

// Socket accept connection function.

SOCKET SocketAcceptConnection(SOCKET ClientSocket, SOCKET ListenSocket) {

ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);

if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {

    printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    std::cout << "Server closing in 5 ";

    for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--){

        Sleep(1 * 1000);

        cout << i << " ";

    }

    cout << "Server closing now!" << endl;

    return 1;

}

closesocket(ListenSocket);

return 0;

}

Here is my j420s.h file.
#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
// #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "10187"
int SocketInit(int, WSADATA*);
int SocketAddrInfo(int, addrinfo*, addrinfo*);
SOCKET SocketCreate(SOCKET, addrinfo* );
int SocketBind(int, SOCKET, addrinfo* );
int SocketListen(int, SOCKET, addrinfo* );
SOCKET SocketAcceptConnection(SOCKET, SOCKET );
```

The access violation is somewhere in this function:

```
int SocketAddrInfo(int iResult, addrinfo* MySocket, addrinfo* MySocketResult){

iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, MySocket, &MySocketResult);

if (iResult != 0) {

    printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);

    WSACleanup();

    return 1;

}

return iResult;

}
```

I call the function like so:

```
iResult = SocketAddrInfo(iResult, &MySocket, MySocketResult);
```

I believe it's something to do with my pointers...

Again, any help would be great! Thanks again!

Comment: "The access violation is somewhere in this function" is this sure? Is this confirmed with a debugger or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result from `getaddrinfo()` will be thrown away on returning from the function `SocketAddrInfo()`, and `MySocketResult` in function `main()` remains `NULL`.

After that, this `NULL` is passed to `SocketCreate()`, and it is dereferenced via `MySocketResult`. It should cause crush.

You should pass a pointer to `MySocketResult` to `SocketAddrInfo()` and have `getaddrinfo()` modify it.

```
int SocketAddrInfo(int iResult, addrinfo* MySocket, addrinfo** MySocketResult){
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, MySocket, MySocketResult);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    return iResult;
}
```

How to call:

```
iResult = SocketAddrInfo(iResult, &MySocket, &MySocketResult);
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a million! Works perfectly!